# C# - String sorting by other string as helper

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

Is there a .NET build-in method that would solve my scenario?

1. Got an array of strings ex. `{ "Mark", "Tom", "Mat", "Mary", "Peter" }`
2. I use string `"Ma"` as sorting string helper
3. My array result is `{ "Mark", "Mary", "Mat", "Tom", "Peter" }`

I know that function solving this would be easy, but I'am interested is such method exists.

PS.
Using .NET 4.0

Comment: The strings that have the matching index that needs to be sorted. What about the other strings, that do not have the matching string? If you want, you can filter out all the matching string and sort them and finally append the list with remaining elements.

Comment: What's the benefit of sorting elements that match only the specified prefix while leaving the other elements in their original relative ordering?  Do the sorted elements always end up at the beginning?

Comment: Homework, if so please tag it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using .Net 3.5 (and above) the [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx) and [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) methods in Linq will be able to do what you want. eg:

```
var ordered = strings.OrderByDescending(s => s.StartsWith("Ma")).ThenBy(s => s);
```

Comment: This one's linq-fu is strong. +1

Answer (score 1):

I think that method does not exist.
I solved with this:

```
public static string[] Sort(this string[] list, string start)
{
    List<string> l = new List<string>();
    l.AddRange(list.Where(p => p.StartsWith(start)).OrderBy(p => p));
    l.AddRange(list.Where(p => !p.StartsWith(start)).OrderBy(p => p));
    return l.ToArray();
}
```

So you can do

```
string[] list = new string[] { "Mark", "Tom", "Mat", "Mary", "Peter" };
string[] ordered_list = list.Sort("Ma");
```

---

If you need to order elements with your string and leave others unsorted, use this:

```
public static string[] Sort(this string[] list, string start)
{
    List<string> l = new List<string>();
    l.AddRange(list.Where(p => p.StartsWith(start)).OrderBy(p => p));
    l.AddRange(list.Where(p => !p.StartsWith(start)));
    // l.AddRange(list.Where(p => !p.StartsWith(start)).OrderByDescending(p => p));
    return l.ToArray();
}
```